# how can i add button to this code to apply this effect on my image i am making an image editor app

Tags: android

Filter filter=SampleFilters.getLimeStutterFilter();
 outputImage = filter.processFilter(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource
            (this.getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.man), 640, 640, false));
            imageView.setImageBitmap(outputImage);

Comment: just add butoon and  add this code onclick listener

Comment: sir i have done the same but still its giving me an error in the getApplicationContext() this code is red.

Comment: can you post Screen shot or cat log

Comment: yes sir i have already taken a screen shot but i dnt knw how i show you..

Comment: Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\Abdullah\AndroidStudioProjects\ImageProcessing\app\src\main\java\com\example\abdullah\imageprocessing\MainActivity.java
Error:(39, 32) error: cannot find symbol method getApplicationContext()
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.991 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings

Comment: THIS IS THE catlog sir

Comment: are you using fragments.? or Activity .?

Comment: sir this is simple main activity

Comment: i have included a library in my code for effects this is the simple effects code but i dnt knw how add button to it to apply this through button on my image

Comment: library in Gradle.?

Comment: yes sir a library in gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getApplicationContext()` does not exist in the class Fragment. It does exist, however, in the `class Activity`, so you can use `getActivity()` .!
and If you are in Activty use Your Class Name like `MainActivity.this`

Comment: and sir i am applying these effects on a drawable image  if i upload any image from gallery then what are the changes that i made to this piece of code

Comment: filter.processFilter(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource (this.getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.man// here you have to add image  //R.drawable.yourimage)

Comment: and if i want to apply this effect on an image which is uploaded from gallery please i need help..?